# CentOS 5.5, related to EPEL

Tags: centos5

Which EPEL package is better for CentOS, and how i am able to find out whether my CentOS 5.5 is 64-bit or 32bit?

Second Problem

in following command I am not able to execute the 3rd command (I have enabled the EPEL5)

```
1) wget -P /tmp http://centos.karan.org/el5/extras/testing/SRPMS/xmlrpc-c-1.06.18-1.el5.kb.src.rpm
2) rpmbuild --rebuild /tmp/xmlrpc-c-1.06.18-1.el5.kb.src.rpm
3) sudo yum -y --nogpgcheck localinstall /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64/xmlrpc-c-*.rpm
```

Comment: What is the error output of your command?

Answer (score 1):

`uname -a` or `uname -pi` will show you the architecture of your system. In this context, "i386" or "i686" are 32-bit architectures. "x86_64" is 64-bit.

For 64-bit, you'll see something like:

```
[root@xtr ~]# uname -a
Linux xtr 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 6 20:13:52 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For a 32-bit server, you'll see:

```
[root@dx ~]# uname -a
Linux dx 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:03:59 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Following command would give you the architecture:

```
arch
```

Check out the path of you local rpm. Ensure that it exist at the path you are specifying.